# Dynamically select column content based on other column from the same row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.6.1. Lets say my data frame looks like:

```
+------------+-----+----+
|categoryName|catA |catB|
+------------+-----+----+
|     catA   |0.25 |0.75|
|     catB   |0.5  |0.5 |
+------------+-----+----+
```

Where `categoryName` has String type, and `cat*` are Double. I would like to add column that will contain value from column which name is in the `categoryName` column:

```
+------------+-----+----+-------+
|categoryName|catA |catB| score |
+------------+-----+----+-------+
|     catA   |0.25 |0.75| 0.25  | ('score' has value from column name 'catA')
|     catB   |0.5  |0.7 |  0.7  | ('score' value from column name 'catB')
+------------+-----+----+-------+
```

I need such extraction to some later calculations. Any ideas?

Important: I don't know names of category columns. Solution needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spark 2.0**:
You can do this (for any number of category columns) by creating a temporary column which holds a map of categroyName -> categoryValue, and then selecting from it:

```
// sequence of any number of category columns
val catCols = input.columns.filterNot(_ == "categoryName")

// create a map of category -> value, and then select from that map using categoryName:
input
  .withColumn("asMap", map(catCols.flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c), col(c))): _*))
  .withColumn("score", $"asMap".apply($"categoryName"))
  .drop("asMap")
```

**Spark 1.6**: Similar idea, but using an array and a UDF to select from it:

```
// sequence of any number of category columns
val catCols = input.columns.filterNot(_ == "categoryName")

// UDF to select from array by index of colName in catCols
val getByColName = udf[Double, String, mutable.WrappedArray[Double]] {
  case (colName, colValues) =>
    val index = catCols.zipWithIndex.find(_._1 == colName).map(_._2)
    index.map(colValues.apply).getOrElse(0.0)
}

// create an array of category values and select from it using UDF:
input
  .withColumn("asArray", array(catCols.map(col): _*))
  .withColumn("score", getByColName($"categoryName", $"asArray"))
  .drop("asArray")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. If you are using scala you can use the Dataset API in which case you would simply create a map which does the calculation.
2. You can move to RDD from dataframe and use a map
3. You can create a UDF which receives all relevant columns as input and do the calculation inside
4. you can use a bunch of when/otherwise clauses to do the search (e.g. when(col1 == CatA, col(CatA)).otherwise(col(CatB)))

Comment: 1.) Dataset API is from Spark 2.0.0, right? I am using 1.6.1
2.) Hmm, maybe, I will check it.
3.) But I will loose column name context inside udf, right ?
4.) Not dynamic

Comment: spark 1.6.1 has dataset API in scala (it was changed in 2.0). When moving to UDF you can use the column name by setting the order.